# How do I run a py file inside a virtual environment on Windows 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help understanding venv and project management on a Windows 7 system.

I have installed Python 3.7.4. Running the command 'pip list' results in the following:

```
Package     Version
pip         19.0.3
setuptools  40.8.0
```

Under the path *C:\Projects\NeuralNetworks* I have the following files/folders:

```
project_env #virtual environment created with venv
main.py
```

When activating my virtual environment 'project_env\Scripts\activate.bat' the command 'pip list' results in:

```
Package     Version
numpy       1.16.4
pip         19.0.3
setuptools  40.8.0
```

When I go to run main.py I get the error "NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined".

```
#main.py
import numpy as np

print(numpy.version.version)
input('Press enter to continue...')
```

I expect to see the version of numpy but instead I get the error that numpy is not found which tells me I don't really understand how these directories work.

**Solution:** I added runserver.bat to my project directory with following.

```
CALL C:\Projects\NeuralNetworks\project_env\Scripts\activate.bat
python C:\Projects\NeuralNetworks\main.py runserver
```

I run the runserver.bat and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Add the full error please

Comment: How are you running main.py? From the command-line or by double-clicking the file?

Comment: I would like to be able to double click the file but the window just opens and closes immediately. When I run the file from the cmd.exe I get 'NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined.

Comment: You have to activate the venv in the same console you run the script.

Comment: Ok, after activating it and changing print(numpy.version.version) to print(np.version.version) I was able to get the result I wanted. That leaves the question of can I just double click the file and get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a .bat file where you added some code inside to activate the environment first and then run your python file.

something like :

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d ..\env\Scripts & activate & cd /d    ..\foldername & python main.py
```

Reference : [A Python script that activates the virtualenv and then runs another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927567/a-python-script-that-activates-the-virtualenv-and-then-runs-another-python-scrip/47422656)