# Running commands within virtualenv in python

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am trying to run a python script under python 2 virtualenv. How to run it via batch script/ python script?

I have installed both python2 and python 3 and created virtual env too. I tried it invoking via python script but it didn't even enter the virtualenv. Then i tried the below batch script. But It just executed the first line of the code. i.e just activating the virtual environment. but other lines are not getting executed.

I even tried to execute the 1st line of batch script separately in a bat file and then invoke others using perl/python. but none of them worked.

Please do provide a way to execute these commands either using python script or 
a batch file, which I will need to run it via perl/python

The batch file i used :

```
C:\venv-2\Scripts\activate
pushd <some path>
python test.py
deactivate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the the batch file executed by giving,

```
C:\venv-2\Scripts\activate & pushd <some path> & python test.py & deactivate
```

inside the batch file. And used perl script to call the batch file

```
system('start test.bat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just directly use the virtualenv's Python interpreter:

```
pushd some_path
c:\venv-2\scripts\python test.py
popd
```

Comment: I tried this, the script runs only in a virtual environment. So using the virtualenv's python interpreter directly dnt work

Answer (score 0):

Not having a Windows environment to hand, this is a non-answer for *nix which might be adapted to Windows.

Instead of calling the venv bin directly, try activating it within a script. For example:

```
# my-script.sh

# activate 
source venv/bin/activate

# this should be in the venv
which python3
python3 -c 'print("Hello from python3")'
```

Then `$ bash my-script.sh` should print out which python3 it thinks is in use *within* the script.

See also [A Python script that activates the virtualenv and then runs another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927567/a-python-script-that-activates-the-virtualenv-and-then-runs-another-python-scrip) for the same idea done better...