# Can I separate some long expression of BAT file into several lines?

Tags: batch-file

How can I split some long expression of  BAT file into several lines (for convenient reading)? For example, I have a long line:

```
call "%NUNIT%\nunit-console.exe" /out="%~dp0%file_name%.out" /err="%~dp0%file_name%.err" /noshadow /xml="%~dp0%file_name%.xml" "%~dp0%file_name%.dll"
```

I want to get the more readable variant, for example three lines instead of one:

```
call "%NUNIT%\nunit-console.exe" /out="%~dp0%file_name%.out" 
  /err="%~dp0%file_name%.err" /noshadow /xml="%~dp0%file_name%.xml" 
  "%~dp0%file_name%.dll"
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long commands split over multiple lines in Vista/DOS batch (.bat) file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '^' character to split the line:

```
call "%NUNIT%\nunit-console.exe" ^
/out="%~dp0%file_name%.out" ^
/err="%~dp0%file_name%.err" ^
/noshadow ^
/xml="%~dp0%file_name%.xml" ^
"%~dp0%file_name%.dll"
```