# Batch File FOR loop using variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I extracted the last line of a text file using the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%m in (message_log.txt) do (
   Set lastline=%%m
)
```

My goal is if the variable `%lastline%=="☺§☻PDF` file has been aborted.
then to display one output and if not exit.  But I think the first three characters are messing it up.  I am trying this:

```
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in (%lastline%) do (
    if %%e==aborted. (
        echo pdf not filed
    )
Pause
```

but the file just exits, with no pause and no output.

I can get this to work if instead of using `%lastline%` I refer to a file as I did in the first for loop, however I cannot get it to work with a variable.

***What is the correct syntax to use a FOR loop to search inside a predefined variable?***

If it is simpler ***my ultimate goal is to echo an error message if the last line in my text file contains the string "abort".***  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're missing a `)`. Open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking it to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is OK, just missing the check.

```
for /f "delims=" %%m in (message_log.txt) do Set lastline=%%m

If "%lastline%" neq "%lastline:abort=%" ^
  Echo error message the last line in message_log.txt contains the string "abort"
```

With findstr

```
for /f "delims=" %%m in (message_log.txt) do Set lastline=%%m

Echo %lastline%|Findstr /i "abort" 2>&1 >Nul && ^
  Echo error message the last line in message_log.txt contains the string "abort"
```

With Gnuwin32 tools installed

```
tail -n 1 message_log.txt|grep "abort" >NUL && ^
  Echo error message the last line in message_log.txt contains the string "abort"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions!  I used the first one and it worked fantastic!  I did have to get rid of the hat ^ though.  I am not sure why it was there but it wouldn't recognize the next line of code if it was present.

Comment: The caret `^` as the last char is the [line continuation char to split long lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-windows-vista-batch-bat-file)