# Curl request not executed as expected

Tags: curl, terminal, request, twilio

I have been trying to send a curl request to twilio, however request is failing. The request template is the following:

```
curl -X POST "https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/FlexFlows" \
--data-urlencode "ChannelType=whatsapp" \
--data-urlencode "Enabled=true" \
--data-urlencode "IntegrationType=studio" \
--data-urlencode "ContactIdentity=whatsapp:+xxxx" \
--data-urlencode "FriendlyName=Flex WhatsApp FlexFlow" \
--data-urlencode "Integration.FlowSid=FWxx" \
--data-urlencode "ChatServiceSid=ISxx" \
-u ACxx:yourAuthToken​
```

I have correctly inserted some custom data on this request, but still fails. Seems like if my terminal is reading above request line by line, instead of taking it as a whole package of information. Below you could find what I get on my terminal when a look for my curl version and a image of the issue I have experience. Any idea on how to make this request right?

```
C:\Users\xxxx>curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

[Evidence request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfQAq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example and using `\` to separate commands to multiple lines is usually for a Linux console.

Given that you're using Windows you need to use the caret `^` symbol for multiline commands:

```
curl -X POST "https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/FlexFlows" ^
--data-urlencode "ChannelType=whatsapp" ^
--data-urlencode "Enabled=true" ^
--data-urlencode "IntegrationType=studio" ^
--data-urlencode "ContactIdentity=whatsapp:+xxxx" ^
--data-urlencode "FriendlyName=Flex WhatsApp FlexFlow" ^
--data-urlencode "Integration.FlowSid=FWxx" ^
--data-urlencode "ChatServiceSid=ISxx" ^
-u ACxx:yourAuthToken​
```

See also this SO question: [Split long commands in multiple lines through Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/split-long-commands-in-multiple-lines-through-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand de confusion. It worked perfectly with your solution.