# Splitting long commands with caret (^) not working with Piping (|) in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, pipe, escaping, line-continuation

The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69068/3705191) state that long commands can be split into multiple lines via the use of the caret character (`^`). One answer provides a technical description:

> **the caret** and **the newline** that follows it **are removed** entirely from the command

However, this doesn't always seem to work when **piping** commands and using the piping symbol (`|`).

Take a look at the following examples:

---

> Code to split:
>
> ```
> dir | sort
> ```

###### ❌ DOES NOT WORK

```
dir ^
| sort
```

###### ✅ WORKS #1

```
dir ^
 | sort
```

<sup>Notice the space in 2nd line</sup>

###### ✅ WORKS #2

```
dir |^
sort
```

---

Would love to know why this is the case :)

Answer (score 2):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/3705191) states, somewhat cryptically, the full technical definition of how the caret (`^`) works is as follows:

#### A caret at the end of the line:

- removes the newline that follows *(e.g. turning 2 lines into 1)*
- **escapes** the first character of the next line
- removes the caret symbol (`^`) you typed

Since the piping symbol `|` is the *first* character in the next line, it will be *escaped* and thus lose its special meaning and just be interpreted as a text character.

---

##### Examples:

```
dir ^
/B
```

Turns into:

```
dir ^/B
```

The `^` character is the *escape character*. The forward slash `/` carries no special meaning, so escaping it has no effect, making the command work as expected and effectively turning it into this:

```
dir /B
```

---

However, look at this:

```
dir ^
& echo hello
```

Turns into:

```
dir ^& echo hello
```

Which *escapes* the special `&` character (which has the special meaning of executing the right command *after* the left one). You will get an error since all of `& echo hello` will be sent as parameters to the `dir` command.

---

Which means that something like this *will* work:

```
dir ^
& & echo hello
```

Turns into:

```
dir ^& & echo hello
```

The first `&` is escaped, while the second `&` is interpreted correctly. This will run `dir ^&`, which sends `&` (raw text character) as the directory parameter for `dir`, *and then* run `echo hello` because of the second `&` character working as normal. `dir ^&` will fail because "&" is no valid directory, and then `echo hello` will print out "hello".

---

Returning to **piping**, let's look at the example you provided that's not working:

```
dir ^
| sort
```

Turns into:

```
dir ^| sort
```

The piping symbol `|` will be escaped and *not* be interpreted as piping (it will appear as text character). And thus, "| sort" will be sent as parameters to the `dir` command, which won't find the directory, and fail.

---

To solve this, as you already figured out, you need to **add a space** at the start of the next line.

This way, the *space* will be escaped, while the subsequent pipe symbol `|` will be interpreted as normal:

```
dir ^
 | sort
```

Turns into:

```
dir ^ | sort
```

Which is effectively:

```
dir | sort
```