# Split long command over multiple lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, terminal, windows-11

```
@echo off
echo "Hello"

echo "Hello ^
my name is Florian"
```

I have read the post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/split-long-commands-in-multiple-lines-through-windows-batch-file) where it is taught that you can split a long command in MS DOS with ^
However above example does not print "Hello my name is Florian" . Instead, I get an error "Misspelled command my or the command my could not be found"
What do I do wrong?

Comment: remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting forces the parser to do some things differently (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) if you like rabbit holes). So either don't use quotes or escape them:

```
@echo off
echo Hello ^
unquoted string
echo ^"Hello ^
quoted string^"
```

Output:

```
Hello unquoted string
"Hello quoted string"
```